# Recursive function from Pine-script to Python

Tags: python, recursion, pine-script, moving-average

I am trying to convert the following Pine function (exponentially weighted moving average with alpha = 1 / length) into Python to apply to a Pandas column of a dataframe df (the src in the Pine code below). "sma" refers to the simple moving average and sma[1] refers to the sma at the previous point:

```
pine_rma(src, length) =>
alpha = 1/length
sum = 0.0
sum := na(sum[1]) ? sma(src, length) : alpha * src + (1 - alpha) * nz(sum[1])
```

I have put together the following Python code but what would be the best way to start the recursion (line r=[0])?

```
def rolling_apply(group, length):
    alpha = 1/length
    r = [0]
    for x in group.x[:-1]:
        r.append(alpha * r + (1-alpha)*r[-1])
    group.r = r
    return group
    
df.r = df.groupby(df.index).apply(rolling_apply).r
```

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the
[intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).  
"Show me how to solve this coding problem?" is off-topic for Stack Overflow.
You have to make an honest attempt at the solution, and then ask a *specific* question about your implementation.
Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing tutorials and documentation.

Comment: Also check [can someone help me?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question).  Since you haven't analyzed the differences between what you have, and what you want, nor made any apparent effort to improve your "found" code, you don't yet have a Stack Overflow question; rather, you seem to want to use this as a coding or tutorial service.

Comment: Apologies, I will have another look

Comment: But the question is still valuable.